# Question about abelian groups, $\mathbb{Z}$-modules and homomorphisms.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

I am interested in proving the following issue:

> Let $M,N$ be abelian groups then every $\mathbb{Z}$-module homomorphism $f:M\longrightarrow N$ is a homomorphism of abelian groups.

Comment: If $f$ is a $\Bbb{Z}-module$ homomorphism, this means that for $n \in \Bbb{Z}$ and $x \in M$, you have $f(nx) = n f(x)$. Can you see why this is the same thing as a group homomorphism? Can you see how to re-phrase "$nx$" as just being something about the abelian group, instead of a $\Bbb{Z}$-module structure?

Comment: It's even more elementary in this direction. A module morphism is always a morphism of abelian groups, whatever the base ring. What is special about $\mathbb{Z}$ is that the converse is true: $\mathbb{Z}$-module morphisms are nothing more than group morphisms (which is what @Nick is explaining).

Answer (score 0):

The $\mathbb Z$-module structure on $M$ agrees with the abelian group structure on $M$ and extends it by scalar multiplication $$nx = x + \dots + x, \\-nx = -x-\dots -x$$ for $x \in M$ and $n\in \Bbb N$. Since homomorphisms preserve structure, homomorphisms of $\mathbb Z$-modules in particular preserve the abelian group structure - in fact, this is true for *any* module.

What is not true in all modules is the converse: Using the definition of scalar multiplication above, every homomorphism of abelian groups is a homomorphism of $\mathbb Z$-modules. This is why it is frequently stated that studying abelian groups is the same as studying $\mathbb Z$-modules.